# jquery map and Date() function

Tags: jquery, date, dictionary, unix-timestamp

I had this js/jquery function working well with all browsers (to transform a timestamp to a date) but actually safari gives me a console error at the ">" character. Any one knows another way to get the same effect?

```
var newTimeArray = timeValues.map(t => new Date(t));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) are still fairly new. The old fashioned syntax for this (which should work in all browsers) is

```
var newTimeArray = timeValues.map(function(t){
    return new Date(t);
});
```

Comment: Oh that was all there was to it! I feel sorry I wasted your time and should have googled about arrow functions, anyhow it worked as intended. Thank you very much!